# How to get row index number of second page in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a Datagridview that is bind with a datasource.This datagridview has multiple pages.Suppose every page contains 50 records and after every 50 records page number will changed.If I am on second page of Datagrid and select 5th row of second page then current index should be of the current page not first page.I have done following code

```
 var current = this.fRReportRowBindingSource.Current as FRReportRow;
                if (current != null)
                {
                    if (gvlayoutload.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
                    {                   
                        rowindexfor = gvlayoutload.SelectedRows[0].Index;
                    }
                }
```

Here rowindexfor is 5.So how can i get index of second selected row of bindingsource.That should not be 5.it should contain 50 index of first page and 5 of current page.

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual row index, just offset it by the page:

```
var rowIndex = rowIndexFor + ((pageNumber - 1) * 50)
```

Here, when you're on page 2 you'd get this (literally):

```
var rowIndex = 5 + ((2 - 1) * 50)
```

or `55`.